# Don't show information when i click select form = “id=undefined”

Tags: php, ajax

Help me please.. it show "`select_modelcar.php?brandid=undefined`" when i choose select form but i try to paste this code in url and define id "`select_modelcar.php?brandid=40`", have the results. i want to choose same categories in select form such as when i choose brand "Toyota", it'll show all car model in Toyota brand (Camry, Yaris, etc.).

### when i click select form >>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RecFc.png)

### past in url and define id >>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cm5i.png)

### select_brandcar.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<?php $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db("carspecth");
 ?>
 
<body>

<script>
 function ValueID(){
     document.getElementById("getval").innerHTML = ('select_modelcar.php?brandid='+this.value);;
 };
</script>

    <select name="select_brandcar" id="select_brandcar" onclick="ValueID();" >
    <option>Press Choose</option>
    <?php 
   $sql = sprintf ("SELECT * FROM brand" );
    $res = mysql_query ($sql);
   while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
 printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>" ,$arr['brandid'], $arr['brandname']);
 }
   ?>
<span id="getval"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

### select_modelcar.php

```
<?php
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
include 'include_connectdb.php';
@$varbrandid = $_GET['brandid'];
@$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM maingeneration WHERE brandfk = %s", $varbrandid);
/*id ของตาราง catagory*/
@$res = mysql_query($sql);
printf("<select name='select' id='select'>");
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $arr['maingenerationid'], $arr['maingenerationname']);
}
printf("</select>");
?>
```

Thank you...........!

Comment: try with onChange instead of onclick like onChange="ValueID();"

Answer (score 2):

```
        Please use onchange event instead of onclick and pass the value in the ValueID function.

        Please replace javascript and php code with this:

            <script>
     function ValueID(vid){
        $.ajax({
                    url: 'select_modelcar.php?brandid='+vid,              
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data === 'success') {
                           document.getElementById("getval").innerHTML = data;
                        }
                    }

                });  

     };
    </script>

                <select name="select_brandcar" id="select_brandcar" onchange="ValueID(this.value);" >
                <option>Press Choose</option>
                <?php 
                $sql = sprintf ("SELECT * FROM brand" );
                $res = mysql_query ($sql);
                while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                   printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>" ,$arr['id'], $arr['name']);
                 }
               ?>
            <span id="getval"></span>


In PHP FIle:
<?php
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
include 'include_connectdb.php';
@$varbrandid = $_GET['brandid'];
@$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM maingeneration WHERE brandfk = %s", $varbrandid);
/*id ของตาราง catagory*/
@$res = mysql_query($sql);
$select = "<select name='select' id='select'>");
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $select .= printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $arr['maingenerationid'], $arr['maingenerationname']);
}
$select .="</select>";
echo $select;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: it's not working, result is `select_modelcar.php?brandid=41`

Comment: it's no working too, no result. I view source as '<span id="getval"></span>
' no printf in page select_modelcar.php

Comment: Please alert the data in the javascript code... Check result is coming from php file or not

Comment: Also send the database structure of table

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<?php $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db("carspecth");
 ?>
 
<body>

<script>
 function ValueID(element){
     document.getElementById("getval").innerHTML = ('select_modelcar.php?brandid='+element.value);;
 };
</script>

    <select name="select_brandcar" id="select_brandcar" onclick="ValueID(this);" >
    <option>Press Choose</option>
    <?php 
   $sql = sprintf ("SELECT * FROM brand" );
    $res = mysql_query ($sql);
   while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
 printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>" ,$arr['brandid'], $arr['brandname']);
 }
   ?>
</select>
<span id="getval"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not working, result is `select_modelcar.php?brandid=41`